# get the duration of the gif animation

Tags: android, gif

How can I get the duration of the gif animation that is playing? I want to have its duration, I am using Movie class and the animation is of a single loop. But because of the Movie class it is being played again and again. Can I know how can i get the duration of a single loop?

```
public class GIFView extends View {

    private Movie mMovie;
    private long movieStart;

    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeView();
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeView();
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initializeView();
    }

    private void initializeView() {
        InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(
                R.drawable.imageedit_ball);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (movieStart == 0) {
            movieStart = (int) now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight()
                    - mMovie.height());
            this.invalidate();


        }
    }}
```

Comment: what does duration() rerurn?

Comment: i guess nothing, how can i print the value of the duration?

Comment: use Log.d() and adb logcat

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to play the animated gif once, stop calling invalidate() once you pass the duration.

```
if (movieStart == 0) {
  movieStart = (int) now;
}

if (mMovie != null) {
  int relTime = (int) (now - moviestart);

  if (relTime > mMovie.duration()) {
    relTime = mMovie.duration();
  }

  mMovie.setTime(relTime);
  mMovie.draw(canvas, 
      getWidth() / 2 - mMovie.width() / 2, 
      getHeight() / 2 - mMovie.height() / 2);

  if (relTime < mMovie.duration()) {
    invalidate();
  }
}
```

mMovie.duration() gives you the duration of one loop.